# Change a cell color based on value - VueJs & Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm gathering datas from a JSON file. I would like to change the cell color to green if the value is "OK" and to red if the value is "KO". I'm using a v-simple-table like that :

```
<td :class="OK? 'primary' : 'accent'">{{ item.pcb1 }}</td>
```

With my actual solution, my entire column is green.

Do someone have any idea how to to it properly ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you intend to test the value of `item.pcb1` in the class conditional.  Right now it's always `true` because it tests the literal string "OK", and any string with a value is truthy.

```html
<td :class="item.pcb1 === 'OK' ? 'primary' : 'accent'">{{ item.pcb1 }}</td>
```

This way tests the value of `item.pcb1` instead of a literal string.

Comment: That's working, I tought this would test the value of my line but that was only OK everytime.